# Sortable Grid View on react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a sortable grid view on react native like you can have on your ios or android system. So far I have created a grid with a ListView and Flexbox but I have tried several solution to make it sortable but nothing works. So I was wondering if you know anyother solution to create that grid.

Thanks!

Comment: Any news on this? I have seen sortable list, but no sortable grid. There is a Youtube example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDlfrcM6YBk) which I used to make a sortable grid, but I had problems with scrolling. This is why I am also still searching for a better solution. Maybe scrolling can be improved with technique  described here https://github.com/hayeah/react-native-SortableList

Comment: I decided to create dragable objects. You can see an example right here http://moduscreate.com/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native/

Comment: you refer this article https://medium.com/@preethiraopn1992/react-native-animation-library-a-draggable-sortable-grid-library-android-ios-50a16caf2553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a component called widget and make it draggable thanks to [this tutorial](http://moduscreate.com/animated_drag_and_drop_with_react_native/). So instead of having a ListView I have a component called Grid and then inside that component I created others called Widgets which have a drag and drop animation.

I still use flexbox to order that components in a proper way on the grid component but I decided to change from the ListView to a separate component because I have more flexibility to change the properties and styles of the widget components.